# angular 7 array push() method showing error warning in visual studio code but running properly

Tags: visual-studio-code, angular7, typescript3.0

I recently upgraded my project from angular6 to angular7. Visual studio code started showing warnings on push, length, etc. 
e.g. 
**[ts] Property 'push' does not exist on type '{}'.**

I have already initialized array

```
this.errorMessages = [];
this.errorMessages.push(errorMessage);
```

sameway its showing on length also

```
if(this.model.str.length > 0)
```

**[ts] Property 'length' does not exist on type 'string'.**

But when its run with

> ng serve

its running properly. Any suggestions

Comment: Try to define your string as empty variable like, var str = "" and do same for your array.

Comment: I did that but still error is showing

Answer (score 0):

Correct.

```
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {
  // Define the calss property
  // If we don't want to access class property outside the class then we need to define private
  // private errorMessages = [];
  errorMessages = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.errorMessages.push(this.errorMessages);
    console.log(this.errorMessages.length);
    // Output 1
  }
}
```

Comment: [ts] Identifier expected. 'private' is a reserved word in strict mode. Class definitions are automatically in strict mode. [ts] Cannot find name 'private'. Anyway why private

Comment: If we don't want to access class property outside the class then we need to define private

Comment: That is fine but how it will resolve the error. The above stated error I am getting while using in same class.

Comment: This example working for me and I'm not getting any error. Can you define more code?

Comment: I copied your code in my Visual studio  code. It is showing same error there. Not sure its IDE issue or something else. Anyway thanks